# null-coalescing operator or conditional operator

Tags: c#

Which coding style do you prefer:

```
object o = new object();
//string s1 =  o ?? "Tom"; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string' CS0266
string s3 = Convert.ToString(o ?? "Tom");
string s2 = (o != null) ? o.ToString() : "Tom";
```

s2 or s3?

Is it possible to make it shorter? s1 does not obviously work.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I should also have included that I was looking for "whether or not o is expected to be a string".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I think my preference would be:

```
string s1 = (string)o ?? "Tom";
```

Or:

```
string s1 = (o as string) ?? "Tom";
```

Depending on whether or not `o` is really *expected* to be a `string` or not.  Either way, I prefer these because they better express what's being done, and don't pass this through an unnecessary conversion if `o` is already a `string`.

---

As a general rule, I prefer whichever is clearer and/or actually works.  When working with strings, I often need to write something like this instead:

```
string result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : "Default";
```

...which can't really be done at all with the null-coalescing operator.  On the other hand, if I'm trying to coalesce a large number of values, it's about 500 times better:

```
var result = firstTry ?? secondTry ?? thirdTry ?? fourthTry ?? fifthTry;
```

Try writing that with the ternary operator instead.

If the difference is not this dramatic, if it's just going to be a couple of characters on one line of code, it really doesn't matter, just use whatever you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work, though calling `ToString` on a string feels a bit strange:

```
string s4 = (o ?? "Tom").ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case I'd prefer using the ternary operator since it expresses the intent more clearly and avoids a redundant call to `Convert.ToString()`. In general I would prefer the null coalescing operator if the conversion is to an object of the same type e.g.

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = s1 ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, I tend to use:

```
var s = obj ?? "tom";
```

when `s` is the same type as `obj` without using the `Convert` or any other type of casting.

Then, I use:

```
var s = obj != null 
    ? obj.ToString() 
    : "tom";
```

when I need to cast or have some other kind of transformation on the right side before assigning to the left side...

Just my style of coding, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like either.  Converting object to a specific type is fraught with trouble, it should never be hidden in an expression.  I'd much prefer that, if it bombs, then it does so on a specific statement.  And to make it absolutely obvious to a reader of the code that this conversion is being done.  So, at the very minimum:

```
string s1 = o as string;
string s2 = s1 ?? "Tom";
```